# how to convert google sheet to excel with values only without formula and send it as email

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, worksheet

I'm a newbie here I just wanna know if anyone could help?
I wanna convert my google sheet into a excel with values only without the formulas and send it as an Email and I also wanna have a Copy of the sent Attachment to my Google drive when sent as an Email using Google app script thank you for the help in advance..